# Why matplotlib.pyplot showed the big spaces for hidden data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was very surprised when I saw how matplotlib show many lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
rand_len = np.random.rand(500)
rand_space = np.random.rand(500)
last_pos = 0.0
for i in range(len(rand_len)):
    plt.plot([last_pos, last_pos + 10*rand_len[i]], [1,1],'k-',linewidth=3.0)
    last_pos += 10*rand_len[i] + 1000*rand_space[i]
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

but when I increase the size

[image: resized graph]

In the first picture some points was hidden
I understand that they small. And matplotlib shouldn't plot the solid line.

Maybe the visualization at this point of view is very harder. And i must see raw data or plot full size graph. !?

What would you recommend to plot the scientific data in this case?

**Update1:**

This issue is still opened.
I hope that [this link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5483) can help to someone.

Comment: I don't understand your point here. Obviously the points are easier to see if you zoom in.

Comment: @cel I talking about points which hidden. In this example it is points in the interval  [180000:220000] which hidden in the first picture, but visible in the second picture. I use it in computer science application. And if I does not see the points, I can do the wrong conclusions.

Comment: They are not hidden, just extremely difficult to see with our eyes. Matplotlib  did not purposely not show them, it's you and me who cannot distinguish the blob into several points.

Comment: @cel Thank you. Perhaps I misunderstood, but you talking about the points which are combined into the one. I'm talking about the hidden points. in the first picture they are hidden in the interval [180000:220000]. But when the picture was resized, I can see it. linewidth=3.0  define the minimal display point size. So I think I can saw the 3px circle. =)

Answer (score 0):

Eric Firing (efiring) proposed the answer:

```
plt.plot([last_pos, last_pos + 10*rand_len[i]], [1,1],'k-', marker='.')
```

Instead:

```
plt.plot([last_pos, last_pos + 10*rand_len[i]], [1,1],'k-',linewidth=3.0)
```

More info: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5483#issuecomment-156940871